# Check data appear frequency

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table

```
Date          name   interest
19990221      xxx     2.2
20110210      xxx     2.1
...
19940922      yyy     3.3
20130930      yyy     3.3
...
```

Where Date is discrete, and not every name have interest in every year. I want to return the name which has interest in the past 10 years for every year. How to do that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dates do not look like dates.  Let me assume that they are strings:

```
select name
from table t
where to_number(substr(date, 4)) >= extract(year from sysdate) - 9
group by name
having count(distinct substr(date, 4)) = 10;
```

You would apply similar logic if the `date` is really a `date`, but the functions would be a bit different.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually my date are in integer. May I ask what is sysdate please?

Comment: `sysdate` is a "variable" in Oracle that returns the current date and time.